# Service startup type for Terminal Services

Tags: windows-server-2003, service

What should be the proper startup type for the Terminal Services service on Server 2003? I have noticed on a couple of servers that I manage that the service doesn't always start when the server reboots, and the startup type is set to Manual. Is there any problem with setting the startup to Automatic?

Answer (score 1):

The default is Automatic. There shouldn't be any problem with setting it to that.